# Why was my answer to "Can selective breeding maximize human intelligence without major complications?" deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answer

[The answer in question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/250715/can-selective-breeding-maximize-human-intelligence-without-major-complications/250737#250737).

I started writing it when the question was still open, poured 4 hours of work into it, it got 5 upvotes, and then... it was **silently** closed while I was sleeping, with a perplexing message:

> **This post is hidden.** It was flagged as spam or offensive content and deleted 18 hours ago by CommunityBot.

I took great care to explain a relatively obscure topic (A.) and how it relates to the result of the fictional country of Sophia's policy, expanded upon it into two further complications (B. & C.), and also gave a bit that was present in another later answer (D.). I even tried to give a bit of character voice in C. to keep it interesting.

I couldn't keep it brief, but then again, many of the answers on WorldBuilding that I enjoyed reading *were* long, exhaustive, and thorough, too.

In [the answer's timeline](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/250737/timeline), I see there was a vote, but I don't see any reasoning given.

So what's going on?

Comment: It looks like it a mod flagged it for being "rude/abusive"; the system then deleted it accordingly (there were actually multiple flags on the answer, but that was what tipped it over the edge). I'll let the folks who flagged explain their reasoning if they so desire, but the overall tone and the repeated profanity (e.g. referring to the OP's setup as a "F*CKING SUFFERING-GENERATING IDIOTIC SYSTEM", sans asterisk) likely contributed.

Comment: @HDE226868 Dang, I was trying to do a character voice here, not refer to the OP - I thought it was clear from capital letters, context, and bolding. So I suppose I need to avoid profanity in future answers (I can never remember where *"f##ks"* are allowed for humorous informal emphasis and where not).

Comment: @Dragomok Yeah, we've had a couple of cases where someone went for either something like that or satire, and the intent didn't really come through -- it's generally better to be explicit about that. And as a rule of thumb, yeah, I'd say avoid profanity ("crap" is probably fine, but heavier stuff -- not great).

Comment: @HDE226868 Thanks for the rule of thumb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented by HDE, the content was flagged as rude/abusive, and deletion followed.

As moderators one of our tasks is to keep the posts clean: surgically removing the crap with an edit takes more time than deleting the whole post, time which is not granted we have. And don't forget it's your duty, as OP, to ensure the quality of the post.